# Why is C++ function's inputs become outputs in the blueprint?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I have a blueprint function library "TextManager", and it has a test_function "Test".

Function's declaration is:

```cpp
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "Custom", meta = (Keywords = "testfunction"))
        static void TestFunc(FString & InString, int & InInt);
```

and definition:

```cpp
void UTextFileManager::TestFunc(FString & InString, int & InInt)
{
    InString = "Has changed";
}
```

But when i call it in the bp, the two inputs become output.

Could anyone explain why is this?

Any help would be appreciated!

let me know if you could't get my question!

Comment: You might want to learn a bit about references : https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/passing-arguments-by-reference/

Comment: thanks buddy,i'm gonna work on it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++ (both in Unreal and other use cases), using reference-type parameters is common approach when you want multiple "output" values from a function, and can't use a single return type. For example:

```
void Main() {
 int MyNumber, MyNumber2;
 SetTwoNumbersTo1(MyNumber, MyNumber2);
}

void SetTwoNumbersTo1(int& FirstOut, int& SecondOut) {
 FirstOut = 1;
 SecondOut = 1;
}
```

Frequently, the value of the parameter before the function isn't important, because inside the function it's set to something independent of its initial value . In the example above, `MyNumber` and `MyNumber2` could have been anything, they would still be 1 at the end.

This can help you undesrtand why `UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)` parameters are displayed as outputs by-default. If you specify a parameter as non-const reference, Unreal *assumes the initial value before you call the function isn't imporant*, and is fully determined inside that function, just like in that C++ example.

This is of course not always the case, and sometimes the initial value matters. For example:

```
void Main() {
 int MyNumber = 1;
 int MyNumber2 = 100;
 DoubleTwoNumbers(MyNumber, MyNumber2);
}

void DoubleTwoNumbers(int& FirstNumber, int& SecondNumber) {
 FirstNumber = FirstNumber * 2;
 SecondNumber = SecondNumber * 2;
}
```

In this case, the approach used by-default in Unreal isn't that great. So there's a special specifier, `UPARAM(ref)`, which can make your parameter be shown as an input on the node.

It can be used like so:

```
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
void DoubleTwoNumbers(UPARAM(ref) int32& FirstNumber, UPARAM(ref) int32& SecondNumber) {
 FirstNumber = FirstNumber * 2;
 SecondNumber = SecondNumber * 2;
}`
```

Please note that this isn't always necessary, but only when the initial value of your parameters is important, and you want to set them to something before calling the node.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer,Now i understand why is that:When the function takes a ref as input, it will automatically take it as to-be-changed value so the original value won't matter(in most case)...Appreciate your post.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still have one question: If I don't pass my reference address into the function in blueprint, how does the blueprint determine where to put the return value? Does the blueprint auto new a memory to place the params? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the input is becoming the output is because you are using the “&” sign.

The “&” means that the variable you are passing in, have the same memory address, as the the one you are calling the function with.

Here is a video about references: [c++ references video](https://youtu.be/IzoFn3dfsPA)

Comment: Thanks buddy,I'm gonna check it out!